# How to use cached credentials in Samba/Winbind on Debian Buster?

Tags: debian, xfce, samba, networkmanager, winbind

While using Debian and Windows in mixed environments for a huge amount of time now I am stuck on trying to use cached credentials for logging in within a domain environment. Once I used the credentials to login, I still want to login when the machine isn't connected to the domain controller anymore.

This behaviour is implemented by Windows clients, so that a laptop user can still login. Only mount points can't be used unless a connection is there. I want to achieve the same on my Debian/GNU Linux client.

---

**Further explanation**

The workstation is using Debian Buster with GUI (Xorg, XFCE, LightDM) and Samba (Winbind). It's a pretty much default installation.

```
:~$ uname -a
Linux client-ph-wkst 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
:~$ sudo samba -V
Version 4.9.5-Debian
```

The workstation is sucessfully connected to a domain controller (Samba 4). Everything is working fine. I'm using this setup since Jessie and it's nice. All domain users can login on that machine, are having an auto-created home directory and so on. The only exception to that is the missing offline authentication.

According to the Samba Wiki (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/PAM_Offline_Authentication) the `smb.conf` has been modified to contain `winbind offline logon = yes`.

While testing this it works as expected. When setting winbind to offline manually(`sudo smbcontrol winbind offline`), I can verify that PAM is using cached credentials. Even by unplugging the cable physically I can achieve the same.

**Problem**

But when I unplug the cable and reboot the system, I can't login. It hangs on LightDM logon screen. I can switch to console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I can logon with the system's root account, because this doesn't request the domain controller. When I look into the services with root I can see, that nmbd is not running. By examining it's logs with `journalctl -xe` I see, that it's not starting because of *No local IPv4 non-loopback interfaces available*.

The default network configuration tool in Debian's GUI installation is NetworkManager. With `nmcli general` I can see that I'm **not** connected.

**Solution quick-and-dirty**

Without plugging in the cable physically I manually activate the interface by entering `nmcli connection up pewpewdefaultconnection`. I restart samba and nmbd service. Voilà! It's working. I can enter my credentials, even restart lightdm service and enter everything with my cached credentials.

**Solution nice and clean to be found**

Since I don't want such an ugly solution as described before I am asking you to help me. Is there anyone who as accomplished this in a clean way? I would really appreciate any help.

I don't want to setup a script that makes the calls, that I described before, since they seem to be ugly. I'd like to prefer something in a configuration style if possible.

Note: I tried to use `auto eth0` in network interfaces and make it being grabbed by NetworkManager's configuration file with `managed=true`. This doesn't show any improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted everything and only left `winbind offline logon = yes` in `smb.conf`. Some days later when the eth cable was unplugged I recognized it's working. Huh!?

On another client computer in the network I did the same configuration change in `smb.conf` and I can confirm it's working there, too.